# Joining two Oracle tables to fetch all rows in a column

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I have two Oracle tables product1 and product2(below), Can someone please suggest on how to join them to get the output as Results.

**Product1**

| product | value |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 |
| Banana | 20 |
| Grapes | 30 |

**Product2**

| product | value |
| --- | --- |
| Orange | 30 |
| Apple | 40 |
| Grapes | 30 |

**Results**

| product | value_t1 | value _t2 | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | 40 | 30 |
| Banana | 20 |  | (-20) |
| Grapes | 30 | 30 | 0 |
| Orange |  | 30 | 30 |

Answer (score 1):

Use a `full join` to get all the produces in both tables and then `coalesce()` to treat the non-`NULL` values as `0`:

```
select product, p1.value as value_1, p2.value a value_2,
       coalesce(p1.value, 0) - coalesce(p2.value, 0) as diff
from product1 p1 full join
     product2 p2
     using (product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN T.product IS NULL THEN
            T.product
        ELSE
            T1.product
    END product
    , T.value value_t1
    , T1.value value_t2
    , CASE 
        WHEN T2.value IS NULL THEN
            0 - T.value
        WHEN T1.value IS NULL THEN
            T1.value
        ELSE 
            T1.value - T.value
    END diff
FROM product1 T
    OUTER JOIN product2 T1 ON T.product = T1.product
```

<strike>You have to sure default values of `value` fields are `0`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

In MySql Dialet this will work, Little twist might work for Oracle DB:

```
select
       IF(p1.product IS NULL, p2.product, p2.product) AS product,
       p1.value AS value_t1,
       p2.value AS value_t2,
       IF(p1.value > p2.value, p1.value - p2.value, p2.value - p1.value) AS diff
from product1 p1
LEFT JOIN product2 p2 on p1.product = p2.product;
```